# Do ReSharper and VSCommands play well together?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I just saw the [VSCommands](http://vscommands.com/) extension and it has some pretty nifty features. However I'm currently running ReSharper 5. Will there be any undesirable interactions between these two extensions?

Comment: It behaves fine with R# 7.1 & 8 EAP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had both ReSharper and (the free version) of VSCommands installed for a while with no problems. You do get some duplicate functionality and therefore duplicate menu commands/shortcuts, but you can turn off some of the features of VSCommands in `Tools -> Options -> VSCommands` if you find that a problem.

There is a [feature request](http://getsatisfaction.com/dpstudio/topics/add_an_config_option_to_turn_of_features_that_duplicate_r_features) for VScommands to add a config option to turn off the features that cross over with those of ReSharper, but it has yet to be done.

Answer (score 4):

I've run both of these without any problems so all should be good.

Answer (score 2):

I've occasionally used it, as it has some great features. However, I'm generally working in a large solution, and running it and ReSharper at the same time tends to really bog down my machine.